# Sequelize setter does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I desperately try to call a simple setter method which seems to not exist.

Here is my modeldefinition:

```
var Process = Sequelize.MySql.define('Process',{
name: Sequelize.STRING,
description: Sequelize.TEXT,
duration: Sequelize.BIGINT,
status: {
    type: Sequelize.ENUM(pstatus.unassigned,pstatus.assigned,pstatus.inprocess,pstatus.stopped,pstatus.finished),
    defaultValue: pstatus.unassigned,
    set: function(v){
        console.log('Prozess status updated')
        if(!pstatus.hasOwnProperty(v)){
            return
        }

        this.setDataValue('status',v)
    }
}
}
```

Every call of process.setStatus(pStatus.inprocess) returns in a TypeError

> Possibly unhandled TypeError: Object [object SequelizeInstance] has no method 'setStatus'

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setters are implemented as [javascript setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

This means that the setter will be invoked when you assign to the property

```
process.status = 'done' // this invokes the setter
```